# Xcode 4.3 developer preview 2: Compatibility with older iOS SDKs

Tags: ios, xcode, backwards-compatibility

I work in a testing company and use xcode for obtaining crash and console logs for testing purposes.
I currently have Xcode 4.2 released version (4C199) on a Snow Leopard (10.6.8).

I have apple devices ranging from iOS 3.1.3 till 5.1 beta 2. But on current version of Xcode, I cannot obtain logs from the iOS 5.1 beta 2 device. Rest of the devices show console logs without any problem.

My question is,

After i upgrade to Xcode 4.3, will it still be possible to obtain logs without any compatibility related errors from devices with older iOS versions like 3.1.3 or 4.2.1?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure and we shouldn't discuss beta specifics outside of Apple's developer forums, but I know what you can do in general to avoid compatibility issues with new versions. Whenever I install an Xcode beta I install it in a custom directory (other than Developer) so that my old and new versions can coexist.

Comment: +1 Yes. Yes. Yes. Overwriting ~/Developer with a beta is a recipe for heavy headdesking.